# Установка Qt Windows ( проблема с самой установкой )

Tags: windows, qt, online

Доброго времени суток, ставлю Qt 5.5 на Windows 10 online installer'ом, чтобы сразу поставить все что нужно ( все компиляторы, все платформы и тд. ), загрузка завершается успешно, но установка нет, в каком-нибудь месте установщик зависнет ( всегда в разных ), не подскажите, есть ли способы после смерти процесса заставить установщик не качать все это заново, а просто продолжить установку, или есть ли альтернативные способы для одного Qt Creator поставить все необходимые компоненты.

Answer (score 1):

Все компиляторы платформы и компоненты за один раз и правда не ставятся без ошибок. Практическое решение - выбери сначала одну платформу (например только Qt 5.5  и Qt Creator), а компиляторы и компоненты и другие версии поставь после.

Comment: Ставиться. Ставил на несколько машин - без проблем. Скорее всего проблема в нестабильном интернете.

Comment: Не исключено, время загрузки шло на часы.